# Validating column null values in Yii Framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to validate null values in a column and i have to update another column based on this validation. My request is,

1. Say i have Column 'Type' , if column 'Type' has some value in DB means i have to display tick mark in "Valid" column in CGridView. (Valid column is psuedo column)
2. Column 'Type' has null values means i have to display untick mark in "valid" column.

Please provide any idea over this.

[image]

Comment: show your cgidview code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add New Column in Gridview with

```
array('name' => 'Status',
            'value' => '!empty($data->type) ? "<img />" : "<img tag/>"',
            'type' => 'raw'),
```

you can put your image tag with src in this.

Comment: how to give image source path ? i pasted inside images folder

Comment: just like add <img src="YOUR IMAGE PATH" />

Comment: <img src="ccvv7/images/update.png" /> not working getting error in Grid Valid column

Comment: use like this 'value' => '!empty($data->type) ? "<img src=\"ccvv7/images/update.png\" />" : "<img src=\"ccvv7/images/update.png\" />"',

Comment: Its working, i used image like this                            'value' => '!empty($data->type) ? CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/images/tick.jpg") : CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/images/untick.jpg")' ,